# Retrieving Database Records on Page Load rather than keyup function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an html form input below

```
<input type="text" id="username" value="">
```

when I enter username eg. john and press the enter button, it retrieves database records by using the script below

```
$(function(){
    //var socket = io.connect( 'http://'+window.location.hostname+':3000' );

    $('#username').on('keyup',function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        if(e.which === 13){

            var name = $this.val();
            socket.emit('new user', name, function(response){
                if(response){
                    localStorage.setItem('username',name);
                    $this.val('');
                    $('#userinfo').hide();
                    $('#chat-body').fadeIn();                   
                    loadMessages(); //retrieve messages from Database
                } else{
                    $('.validation').text('Username taken!').fadeIn();
                }

            });
    }
    });

    function loadMessages(){
        $.post('process.php',{method:'retrieve'},function(response){
            $.each(JSON.parse(response),function(i,v){              
                $('.messages').append('<li><div class="msg-lhs"><span class="username">'+v.name+'</span> : <span class="msg">'+v.message+'</span></div><span data-livestamp="'+v.created_at+'" class="msg-rhs"></span></li>');
            });
            $('.messages').animate({scrollTop: $('.messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 500);
        });
    }


});
```

Now what I want is to eliminate keyup function() and pass the username in a hidden form  and then retrieves the database records as soon as the page loads. Can someone help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create a function to retrieve your data. Then you can simply use the below code to retrieve after the page is loaded:

```
window.onload = YourFunction;
```

P.S. Make sure you don't expose your database connection in your code!

Comment: how, I do not understand you

Comment: @akwaeze: First create a function to retrieve your data. Then you can simply use the below code to retrieve after the page is loaded:
   
   `<script>
   function RetrieveData(){
     you above in here
   }
   window.onload = RetrieveData();
   </script>